# Rundeck - what is a difference between logs

Tags: logging, rundeck

I have a problem with logs on Rundeck instance, but what is a difference between logs in /var/lib/rundeck/logs and /var/logs/rundeck
In both I mean about jobs.logs
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At `/var/lib/rundeck/logs` you can find information related to job executions, at `/var/log/rundeck` you can find information about the instance (like the `service.log`, the main Rundeck log file). Take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/maintenance/logs.html#logs).

Regarding `/var/lib/rundeck/logs` logs, you can change the path at the `framework.properties` file (`framework.logs.dir` param) to another partition, just make sure that path is reachable by `rundeck` user.

But definitely, the best way to manage this is to configure Rundeck to use some external log storage (like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Minio](https://min.io/) services), take a look at [this](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/rundeck-s3-log-plugin) plugin.

Comment: So what is the best solution with /var/lib/rundeck/logs storage, because I have to increase disk every tow days and looking for a better solution